# Accessing secure endpoint with X-WP-Nonce?

Tags: rest-api

I set up a custom endpoint using the WP Rest API.
And in that endpoint, I am checking to make sure a user can edit a post before being able to access it.
[image: permissions code]
So obviously, just entering the raw endpoint into the browser will give me a permissions error.
My application is using ajax to retrieve information from this endpoint.
So I dropped

```
wp_localize_script( 'my-script', 'wpApiSettings', array( 
  'root' => esc_url_raw( rest_url() ), 
  'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' )
) );
```

in to my enqueue hook. And then in my ajax call I have this.

```
beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-WP-Nonce', wpApiSettings.nonce );
},
```

But the ajax call still is not working as it still doesn't seem to be able access the endpoint, even though I am sending that header and my user does have 'admin' status. Am I doing this correctly? Is sending that `X-WP-Nonce` header supposed to break the break through the permissions barrier?

Comment: Have you seen [REST API Handbook: Authentication](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/)?

Comment: Never mind. I figured it out. I made a silly mistake and enqueued the main script incorrectly.  Once I fixed that issue, the script works just fine.